# DNS: wildcard domains

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, wildcard

If I have a wildcard domain, is it possible to list specific subdomains that override the wildcard one?

For example:

```
*.domain.com. 3600 IN A 1.2.3.4
foo.domain.com. 3600 IN A 9.9.9.9
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this works.

Comment: Absolutely.  The * record is only consulted if there are no more specific records that match the query.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, like Zoredache says, "this works".

There are some caveats though with wildcards that it's worth knowing:

1. The wildcard matches one *or more* labels, so in your case `foo.bar.domain.com` will be matched by the wildcard, but `bar.foo.domain.com` will return `NXDOMAIN` because the presence of `foo` prevents any sub-domains of `foo` from matching
2. The wildcard match is RRtype specific.  However If the wildcard and override records don't have the same RRtype then the over-riding records will still "hide" the wildcard, but you get `NODATA` (i.e. no answer, `rcode == NOERROR`).

e.g.

```
$ORIGIN example.com.
*     IN A   192.168.1.1
foo   IN TXT "foo"

% dig @localhost foo.example.com. A
(abbreviated)
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 36960
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
```

Comment: Sorry but this is a bit cryptic for me to understand.

Comment: Does a definition of *.foo.domain.com. work to avoid NXDOMAIN for bar.foo.domain.com ?

Comment: @Steve - I believe so, yes.  (I haven't tested it though)