# If you have a *.domain.com CNAME record, does that have less of a priority than a blog.domain.com?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I have some defined CNAME sub-domains on my site:

blog.site.com

wazoo.site.com

I want to add *.site.com support and have all of those wildcard requests get handled by my main web server (the sub-domains reflect other data, like the logged in user's custom data.)  If you have a *.site CNAME, will that work well with the more specific records?

What I want is to have my blog.site.com CNAME work according to the DNS record and then have the wildcard of all the other user specific sub-domains go to my main website, is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DNS: wildcard domains](https://serverfault.com/questions/18074/dns-wildcard-domains)

The above question actually answers the question that this is ok and works fine.

Comment: No, that question's answers do NOT answer this question. A CNAME record is not simply an alternative to an A record with the same IP address as a result, it is a name substitution. Using a CNAME where an additional A record can be used (i.e. where you control the canonical name and it has 1 long-term A record) should be avoided because the CNAME cannot co-exist with other record types for the same name, a fact that can have undesirable side-effects.